# Hibernate executes query only 8 times

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I think that my JUnit test will explain this better than I could with words!

```
    @Test
public void query8times(){

    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        ProspectoRadarQueryBuilder prqb = new ProspectoRadarQueryBuilder("jardeu");
        List<Object[]> prospectosNotas = (List<Object[]>) genericFilterDao.executeSQL(prqb.buildQuery());   
        System.out.println("------------------------------------- "+i);
    }
}
```

The result for that on the console was:

```
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 0
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 1
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 2
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 3
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 4
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 5
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 6
Hibernate:   SELECT * FROM   (   select         p.id,           comparestrings('jardeu', pc.valor) as nota   from           com_prospecto p         inner join com_prospecto_campo pc ON (p.id = pc.id_prospecto)           inner join com_campo c ON (pc.id_campo = c.id AND c.flag_nome = true)    ) as subQuery   where          nota is not null            AND         nota > 0.35  order by           nota desc;
------------------------------------- 7
```

Now lets see the source Code !

```
public List<?> executeSQL(String sql) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query q = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery(sql);

    return q.list();
}
```

I did another test, with another query

```
@Test
public void anotherQuery(){

    for(int i=0; i<15; i++){
        List<Object[]> prospectosNotas = (List<Object[]>) genericFilterDao.executeSQL("select * from com_campo");   
        System.out.println("------------------------------------- "+i);
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

```
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 0
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 1
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 2
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 3
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 4
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 5
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 6
Hibernate: select * from com_campo
------------------------------------- 7
```

So, I´m using Spring Data... What might be the problem?

Comment: How are you running your tests? I can't believe that your original query was named `query8times` is a coincidence. Leads me to believe you might have a test class cached somewhere.

Comment: To make sure, make it print "Testing " + n + " times" and use that *n* in the for loop.

Comment: I suspect you are using a class file which was compiled before you made a change to the `query8times` method.

Comment: This can be a case when you're using eclipse and Build Automatically is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you be creating only one EntityManager?

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

The ^ line should be outside the executeSQL method.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I created only one entityManager as adarshr said. But that was not the problem.
I forgot to commit the transaction and close the entity manager...

This is the final result:

```
 public List<?> executeSQL(String sql) {
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    Session hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    Query q = hibernateSession.createSQLQuery(sql);

    List<?> list = q.list();

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();

    return list;
}
```

Comment: You should post this as a comment or an edit to your original question as this is not an answer.